# How to return multiple result sets when querying in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql. I'm looking  to return 2 result sets, in my query, is this possible? My current query is using 'UNION ALL' where i'm getting dupplicate data.

```
WITH logged_in AS (
      select exists (select 1 from users where user_name = 'z' and password = 'abc') AS logged_in, user_name, user_type
      from users
      WHERE user_name = 'z'
      AND password = 'abc'
     )

     select logged_in, up.user_type, up.page_name, 'page' AS type
     from logged_in AS l
     JOIN user_application_mappings AS up
     ON l.user_type = up.user_type
     UNION ALL
     select logged_in, fm.user_type, fm.feature_name, 'feature' AS type
     from logged_in AS l
     JOIN user_feature_mapping AS fm
     ON l.user_type = fm.user_type
```

i just want my query to return the following:

```
**resultset 1:**

ID, user_name, logged_in, user_type
 1    userA       true     admin

**resultset 2:**

   pageName, Description,  type
    feature a    xx          page
    feature b    xx          feature
```

how can i achieve this?

thanks

Comment: you have to unify datatypes for `union all`, like here: `select 1::text one union all select 'text';`

Comment: how would your `logged_in` ever become false?

Comment: There are some workarounds in some cases, but fundamentally, the Postgres client protocol doesn't support multiple result sets from one query.